# Why is pyparsing removing a named result?

Tags: python, pyparsing

Given the following minimal working example:

```
from pyparsing import *
latex_h  = QuotedString("$")('latex')
reg_text = Word(alphas)('text')
grammar  = OneOrMore( latex_h | reg_text )('line')

sol = grammar.parseString('''dog $x^2$ cat''')
print sol.dump()
```

I expected the output to look like:

```
['dog', 'x^2', 'cat']
- line: ['dog', 'x^2', 'cat']
  - text: dog
  - latex: x^2
  - text: cat
```

but instead I got:

```
['dog', 'x^2', 'cat']
- latex: x^2
- line: ['dog', 'x^2', 'cat']
  - latex: x^2
  - text: cat
- text: cat
```

I don't understand why in the parse tree did the `dog` get left behind? In addition, why are two elements of `text, latex` *outside* the `line`?

Comment: I've only just started working with `pyparsing`, but I think the main thing here is that the named results act as a dictionary, and `sol['text']` therefore can't be both `'dog'` and `'cat'`.

Comment: If you are running the latest pyparsing, you *can* define the results name with a trailing '*', as in `reg_text = Word(alphas)('text*')`. This is equivalent to `reg_text = Word(alphas).setResultsName('text', listAllMatches=True)` and will keep all matched tokens for that results name. However you will lose the relative order/relationship between the interleaved reg_text's and latex_h's.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Russell Borogove says, named results must be unique when on the same parsing level. You can't have a "line" with two or more named elements of the same type (e.g. two "text" or two "latex"), since they'll both use the same key in the underlying dictionary. I'll defer to Paul McGuire regarding the `listAllMatches` solution in the latest PyParsing, seeing as he wrote it and all :)

You can also work around this by attaching parsing actions to "latex_h" or "reg_text", however this won't help if the "latex_h" element requires knowledge of any sibling "reg_text" elements. In which case you will probably need to break up your grammar a bit further, or use a tree-based approach to parsing (working from the lowest element up to the root, by parse actions and/or by iterating through the list of results), rather than a dictionary-based approach.

It's important to note that the the parse tree did *not* leave "dog" behind. It was parsed correctly, it's just that the parsed result did not get assigned to a dictionary. You can access the parsed value like so: `sol.line[0]`

As for why 'latex' and 'cat' appear outside of the 'line', you need to put the OneOrMore definition within a Group().

Here's an example, which applies a parse action to the `reg_text` element at the time it's parsed (rather than when any parent element, like `grammar` is parsed). It does not solve the 'named result' issue you are having, but without context on what you are trying to achieve with your parser I can't suggest a solution.

```
from pyparsing import *
latex_h  = QuotedString("$")('latex')
reg_text = Word(alphas)('text')
grammar  = Group(OneOrMore( latex_h | reg_text ))('line')

def parse_reg_text(s, loc, toks):
    if toks.text == 'dog':
        return "atomic " + toks.text
    else:
        return "ninja " + toks.text

reg_text.setParseAction(parse_reg_text)

sol = grammar.parseString('''dog $x^2$ cat $y^3$''')
print sol.dump()
```

This gives the following output:

```
[['atomic dog', 'x^2', 'ninja cat', 'y^3']]
- line: ['atomic dog', 'x^2', 'ninja cat', 'y^3']
  - latex: y^3
  - text: ninja cat
```